# Reminders: repeat reminder based on date last completed

Tags: reminders

I'd like to be able to add custom repeat periods for Reminders starting from the date / time I last completed the item.

eg. Service Car: Repeats 3 months after last completion

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps consider Calendar, as it offers more functionality. Thanks for the link, had macs since system 6 so here is a link for you : https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/calendar/welcome/mac

Comment: Calendar definitely does have more functionality than reminders. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to have the functionality I'm looking for to achieve this particular outcome; a semi-fluid notification date scheduled to repeat at a given period after the last completion date. An overdue task would need to be scheduled at the date of completion + the repetition period, not the date of last schedule + the repetition period.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been waiting for this feature for years, and Apple never adds it. Useful for so many things: If I want to get a haircut every 6 weeks, but I’m late getting it by a week or two when I’m busy, I still want to wait 6 weeks before I get another haircut after that.

The point of Reminders is that I can record them and stop thinking about them. If I have to say to myself, “oh, it’s not time yet for a haircut because I just got one 4 weeks ago”, that’s having to remember it.  Or if have to adjust the Reminder, that’s more effort than I should have to put into it.

So I’ve been using GoodTask for about 2 years now, simply because it offers “Repeat after completion”.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question above

Comment: Hi ! could you add a bit more about GoodTask, instead of the first two paragraphs? It will make the answer useful for all. Link is the minimum you'd want to add. Also,  see [answer] page about more guidance.

Comment: This is a great answer in that it confirms this isn’t native to reminders and offers anothe solution. +1 by me